# Simple xslt error:

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xslt

So, I'm running the following code in IE11:

```
var processor = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
var xslt = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");                 
xslt.load(xsl_str_loc);
processor.stylesheet = xslt;
```

On the fourth line, this fails with the exception `Error: the data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available`.

the xml that I"m loading is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <D>
     <xsl:for-each select="/D/R">
        <xsl:sort select="C3" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="C5" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="C1" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:for-each>
  </D>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've checked the readyState of the xslt, and it is 4.  Is there an easy way that I can trace down the missing resource and wait until it's loaded?  Why is it failing when I assign the xslt to the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `xslt.async = false;` before calling the `load` method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say that I tried this in the body.  It did not work.

Comment: Do you get the same error when having set `async` to `false`?

Comment: Yes, it fails with the same stack trace.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong.  It's a different exception, originally.  Our application caught it and rethrew it.  Thank you!